# Beginner resources device design/assembly

Tags: microcontroller, embedded, programming, assembly

During the summer I would love to get into electrical engineering. As background, I'm a computer scientist and as such, I have a fairly decent grasp of basic circuit design and electricity, which means I don't have to start entirely from scratch. I have however no experience with developing micro circuits or anything of the kind.

As an end-goal I would like to design/assemble ARM powered devices, using existing components. I am however aware that this is not a task for a beginner.

My problem is, that I'm not entirely sure where to start, or to what extend I need to educate myself in electrical engineering to accomplish my end-goal. I could buy a BeagleBoard or an Arduino to practice with, but I'm not sure if that would be of use to me or not.

What should I start learning first with my end-goal in mind and what tools should I obtain to assist me?

Comment: It is not clear to me what your end-goal is. 'existing components' - I guess nobody here makes his own components! Or do you mean board-level products? And what 'level' are you aiming for - an LPC1114 chip (4K RAM, 32K Flash) is used 'bare metal', a Raspberry Pi (512MB RAM, Flash card) is used mostly with a Linux distro. What is your programming language expertise?

Comment: The specifications would depend on the device of course, but I do own a RaspberryPi, that would actually be a good example of what something I'd like to be able to build myself. As for programming, I have years of experience in programming in various languages, including C, Java, Pascal, ... I have little experience with programming in assembly languages, but I'm very familiar with how they work, it wouldn't take long to learn. I'm also familiar with operating system concepts.

Comment: I have years of experience in tinkering with microcontrollers, including writing the Jal language and original compiler. *Building* something like the PI is *way* over my head. And it would cost much more than the Pi itself, so instead I buy and use it. An LPC1114 board on the other hand is a very different story. - C is OK for microcontrollers, but I prefer C++. Some occasional assembly can be handy, but only for very very time critical parts, or context switching.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An Arduino is a great way to get into the world of embedded devices and systems, which is what I think you are (mostly) referring to. With Arduino, you already have all of the components assembled for you, which is the hardest part, in my opinion. You can then become familiar with the important aspects of embedded devices, such as interrupts, memory-mapped I/O, etc. There are lots of choices, and you can work with a ATMega or ARM core processor, depending on the board you choose. I'd personally recommend beginning with the ATMega, (as comes on the UNO), as you can find lots of information for low-level operations later on.

Once you feel comfortable using the integrated IDE, you can switch to something more advanced, and program using just the barebones (registers, low-level syntax, etc). There are plenty of tutorials showing how to use eclipse IDE with Arduino. It's important to become familiar with the barebones, as most board-level microcontrollers will require you to interface with them in this manner. Many use C, but depending on the compiler and development environment you choose, you can also use C++, assembly, etc.

Finally, when you are ready, you can then move up to your end goal: creating your own embedded system using just the bare microprocessor. This is difficult, as you'll need to set up a lot of the basics that the Arduino already takes care of, such as the hardware clock and serial interface (most Arduinos actually use another ATMega processor to take care of the serial), but once all is said and done, it's very rewarding.

Comment: This is exactly the thought *one*. On *second* thought what I feel like is *arduino* is a abstraction, if one's going for it then why not go for *NETDUINO* which is another abstraction. personally I don't think there is much learning in *arduino* because of the heavy *abstraction*. I'd rather recommend a 8051 or a AVR if someone ask's to learn.

Comment: Well, embedded devices are part of what I'd like to be able to build, but let's say that for example, I'd like to assemble a small computer like the RaspberryPi. How would I go from a pre-assembled "learning-environment", like the Arduino platform, to assembling something like that? Seeing as the Arduino for example, is fairly "simple" in it's construction, would that be a big step? I assume that it'd require less "embedded-oriented" components, which might take a lot of the work out of your hands?